# Can't download from github Openshift v3

Tags: github, download, redhat, openshift-origin

I installed Openshift origin v3 using vagrant on my computer and created a project and an python component whose source code is hosted on Github.

When a build is started, it shows the error:

`builder.go:204] Error: build error: timeout while waiting for remote repository`

I had the same mistake yesterday for a while, but all of sudden, it worked and my app deployed successfully. Today, I tried to rebuild after some code changes, but couldn't make Openshift download my code from github.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I tried to ping github.com from the vagrant machine, in ssh and it worked.
So I tried to ping again from a docker container executed within the vagrant vm :

```
me@ vagrant ssh
vagrant@ docker run --rm -it openshift/base-centos7 /bin/bash
WARNING: IPv4 forwarding is disabled. Networking will not work.
bash@ ping github.com
ping: unknown host github.com
```

The warning was right, it didn't work. So I restarted the docker daemon from within the vagrant machine, and it solved the problem.

```
vagrant@ sudo service restart docker
```

Link : https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/7840

Answer (score 1):

this could be because of a DNS issue. Are you using the official vagrant openshift image? If you're not, then it might be because of firewalld, try turning that off. There's also `oc cluster up` i might recommend. But bare in mind, you might run into the same issue.
https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/11949

please see this for oc cluster up
https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/docs/cluster_up_down.md

Comment: It is official, I followed these instructions:
https://www.openshift.org/vm/instructions1_2.html

oc cluster up fails "Checking docker client" with the error "cannot communicate with docker"

Event after `oc cluster up --create-machine` which failed too:
-- Checking OpenShift client ... OK
-- Create Docker machine ...
   Creating docker-machine openshift
-- Checking Docker client ... FAIL
   Error: cannot obtain a client for Docker machine "openshift"

Comment: what platform are you on? do you have docker-machine installed on your system?

Comment: I'm on windows. I have docker-machine, the env was not set. Now it is, and the new error was `did not detect an --insecure-registry argument on the Docker daemon`

I solved this, but next error : `could not update OpenShift configuration`

It looks like it's trying to run a new openshift machine without vagrant, which I supposed impossible since i'm on windows.

I'm a little lost.

Comment: oc cluster up doesn't use vagrant, just the virtualbox driver.

Comment: stupid comment. i pressed enter before replying. https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/docs/cluster_up_down.md#windows-with-docker-for-windows

Comment: try to follow the steps as detailed in the link i left above, i think that should help.

Comment: I'm on windows 7, so docker-toolbox is my only solution. I tried the section "Windows with Docker tool-box". Did not work as I said earlier. And now `oc cluster up --create-machine` shows ` Error: Docker machine exists` even if i deleted it on virtualbox and tried to `oc cluster down` it with `--docker-machine=openshift`.

Comment: i figured afterwards that you might be on non-hyperv windows version.did you try removing the virtual machine from the hdd manually? it should be somewhere in C:\Users\[username]\VirtualBox VMs or maybe reboot the system, might have some stale vm running.

Comment: The vm wasn't in this directory. If I understand correctly, oc cluster up is supposed to create a new Openshift environment. But it seems that my "old" one, the all-in-one version installed with vagrant worked at some point (2 days ago). You mentioned a firewall problem, so I just need to solve this, don't I ? I can't disable it. Also, the error has changed today : `builder.go:204] Error: build error: fatal: unable to access _githubpath_': Could not resolve host: github.com; Unknown error`.

Comment: unfortunately the firewalld problem is a fedora problem, not a windows one. what i would suggest at this point is to try and find the stale VM and remove it manually. there are plenty of resources to guide you through that. if that doesn't work, i would suggest just installing a virtualbox with a linux distro and using oc cluster up natively.

Comment: Alright, I still don't know exactly why my problem occurred, but it seems to be fixed, now. Thank you for your help !

Comment: glad i could be of some minimal help :)